# Interacting with a webpage using Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-scraping

I am a programming novice and am trying to create a simple program which will search for a requested book on https://z-lib.org/ and then download the relevant file so that I can then convert it for use on a Kindle.

What is the simplest way to interact with the webpage to complete this search and download using Javascript.

Initial searches have led me to Selenium. Is this the best path to follow and if so would someone be able to provide some pointers for where to start considering I am a beginner?

Thanks

Comment: In theory yes. Now you need to learn a suitable programming language, then install the selenium package and write code that tells selenium to open the website, enter the search term, etc.

Comment: I am familiar with the basics of JS and Python but would like to use JS if possible as I want to integrate this into an Apple Shortcut so that I can ask Siri for a specific book and have it automatically downloaded, converted and sent to a kindle. Could anyone suggest an approachable learning resource that might give me the ability to do this using selenium considering I have never used it before.

Comment: Are you familiar with node/npm? You need to start there. Then get https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver

Comment: If you know JS then Puppeteer is a better choice.